# Is it safe to interrupt a running `npm install` with ^C?

Tags: node.js, npm

By "safe" I mean "easily fixable by running `npm install` again". I suspect I sometimes have broken installations because I interrupt the process, but have no evidence to confirm that this is the cause.

And, if it is not safe, should I always `rm -rf node_modules/` after interrupting npm?

Answer (score 7):

[Answer from @zkat on github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10762#issuecomment-171469693):

> As of **npm@3**, anything that modifies your `node_modules` folder (such as `npm install`) will automatically repair your `node_modules/` folder -- so, if you break things with `^C`, just rerun `npm install` and you're good to go!

Answer (score 6):

It's fine to `^C` just be *sure* to do these 2 things after canceling the process.

- `rm -rf node_modules/` as you stated, as this will **delete** all of the existing installs, this prevents a lot of errors.
- `npm cache clean` just to be certain. This **cleans** the cache and allows you to do a `npm install` on a clean slate.

This is a process that you're going to have to do quite a lot, since a lot of weird npm errors will pop up.

Although, there are almost no install errors that these 2 commands can't fix.